# Next js with express dynamic path handling

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I am trying to create dynamic route for my web application but the path are not working as it suppose to this is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const { parse } = require("url");

app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = express();

  server.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
    app.render(req, res, "/", query);
  });
  server.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
    app.render(req, res, "/home", query);
  });
  server.get("/category", (req, res) => {
    app.render(req, res, "/category");
  });

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
    return handle(req, res, "/", parsedUrl);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

I need to  dynamically get the id from path that will come after url, what is happening is no matter what I write after my local host it always go thrugh server.get(* .. part. please help.

Comment: Why are you using a custom server to handle routing when Next.js provides it's own [built-in routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction) out-of-the-box?

Comment: firstly thank you for your reply. the thing is I am new to web application so I failed to suggest any changes at admin panel and this project works with scanning of qr code and generating URL based on it. so If you know how to manipulate this server js that would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that you can use `render()` with next.js? The best approach is to use express only for api, next.js for frontend

Comment: can you link any example of that?

Comment: [https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js) this is how official example looks like